# Is my proof that $\operatorname{Isom_n}{\mathbb R^n}$ is compact right?

Tags: lie-groups

I previously [did this exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081151/group-of-isometries-is-closed-in-gl-n1):

> Prove that $\operatorname{Isom_n}{\mathbb R^n}$ is a matrix group.
>
> where
>
> $$\operatorname{Isom_n}{\mathbb R^n} = \left \{ \left ( \begin{array}{cc} A & 0 \\ V & 1 \end{array} \right )  \mid A \in O(n) (\mathbb K), V \in \mathbb R^n \right \} $$

I forgot to answer whether it is compact so I am answering it now:

Let $D_n \in O(n)$ be the diagonal matrix with entries $d_{11}=n, d_{22}={1\over n}$ and $d_{kk}=1$ for $k > 2$.

Since the determinant of a diagonal matrix equals the product of the entries in the diagonal we have $\det D_n = 1$ hence $D_n \in O(n)$.

Since $\|D_n\|\ge \sqrt{n}$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm the sequence $D_n \in O(n)$ is unbounded and hence so is $O(n)$.

My problem now is that the limit of $D_n$ has $d_{22}=0$ and is therefore not in $O(n)$ and so

$$\left ( \begin{array}{cc} D_n & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right )  $$

appears to be a sequence in $\operatorname{Isom_n}{\mathbb R^n}$ such that its limit is not in $\operatorname{Isom_n}{\mathbb R^n}$ contradicting my previous proof that $\operatorname{Isom_n}{\mathbb R^n}$ was closed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take $n=1$.  Can you find a convergent subsequence of $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\m & 1\end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 2):

There is an obvious continuous and surjective map from that group to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: As for your idea for a proof, that the group be closed does not mean that every sequence converges to something: your sequence does not have a limit not only in the group but also in the matrix space containing it. You should review the characterization of closed subsets of a metric space in terms of sequences!

Comment: In any case, your matrix is most certainly not in O(n): you should also review the definition of O(n).

Comment: $O(n)$ is the set of matrices with determinant either $1$ or $-1$. I understand your argument.

Comment: No, that is not O(n). See, for example, the Wikipedia page on the orthogonal group.

Comment: Btw your first comment is the answer to my question. If you replace your answer with the text in that comment I can upvote and accept you.

Comment: My answer answers the question in your title.

Comment: Alright, I will edit the title.

Comment: Well. Now it answers the question that was in the title :-)